# How to delete accidentally installed External Libraries and Scratches and Consoles folders from the file explorer

Tags: phpstorm

I was trying to create a new file in my PhpStorm but instead inadvertently installed the "External Libraries" and "Scratches and Consoles" folders.

I don't need them for the foreseeable future really. I tried to uninstall and reinstall PhpStorm in my Ubuntu 20.04, only to see those two folders still sitting in my file explorer.

Is there I can do to get rid of them?

[image: The External Libraries and Scratches and Console to get rid off]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there I can do to get rid of them?

It's a **standard thing**, everyone has those 2 entries.

You can see them mentioned in the official help / screenshots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html

There is no need to delete them.

- **Scratches and Consoles** used to access [scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/scratches.html) and files for DB Export functionality / [DB query consoles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-database-consoles.html) (in PhpStorm at very least).
- **External Libraries** used to list all entries from the `Include Path` tab at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP` and alike. But that has been reworked a bit a few versions back (the way how it was working in IntelliJ IDEA). Not sure what is used for these days (in PhpStorm).

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne. Much appreciated.

 I did a few projects in my PHPStrorm since I installed it about two months ago. 

And obviously, I played with it creating projects/files in stuff just to learn my way around it and have never seen those two folders, honestly. 

I guess I will have to leave with them from now on LOL

Not to be a PITA, but, last question, I promise: is there any way to hide them from the PS File Explorer?

Comment: I'm not aware of any ways of hiding them. Never looked into getting rid of them (why would I bother: 1) I use scratches from time to time 2) modern framework projects have enough files in the file tree to simply not noticing these two).

Comment: Okey dokey then. Thanks a lot.